# Creating a Loop To get info from form Where the amount of fields can vary

Tags: php, forms, http-post

I have a form that allows users to register into a database. They can register up to a group of 6 at a time. Currently the webpage displays two forms. The first (*userNumberForm*) is just a drop down list where the user picks how many names to register. That gets posted and when the page reloads the 2nd form (*userInfoForm*) runs a while loop to populate the correct number of fields for the user to enter their information in. It also contains a hidden field where the value from the *userNumberForm* is stored. When the *userInfoForm* gets posted the first thing I have the addUser.php (the page it posts to) do is check the number of users and store that in a variable called *userNum*. Currently I have a switch statement based on that variable to get the rest of the information from the form and sanitize the data.

```
case 2:

    $FirstName1=$_POST['FirstName1'];
    $FirstName2=$_POST['FirstName2'];

    $FirstName1 = stripslashes($FirstName1);
    $FirstName1 = mysql_real_escape_string($FirstName1);
    $FirstName2 = stripslashes($FirstName2);
    $FirstName2 = mysql_real_escape_string($FirstName2);
break;

case 3:

    $FirstName1=$_POST['FirstName1'];
    $FirstName2=$_POST['FirstName2'];
    $FirstName3=$_POST['FirstName3'];

    $FirstName1 = stripslashes($FirstName1);
    $FirstName1 = mysql_real_escape_string($FirstName1);
    $FirstName2 = stripslashes($FirstName2);
    $FirstName2 = mysql_real_escape_string($FirstName2);        
    $FirstName3 = stripslashes($FirstName3);
    $FirstName3 = mysql_real_escape_string($FirstName3);

break;
//... and so on
```

As you can see this is starting to be a lot of code. I am hoping there is a way to set something up like this:

```
$x = 1;
while($x < $userNum)
{
$FirstName.$X=$_POST['FirstName.$X'];
$FirstName.$X = stripslashes($FirstName.$X);
$FirstName.$X = mysql_real_escape_string($FirstName.$X);
++$x;
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but that is the format I am looking for. I don't fully understand variable variables yet, Or maybe I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be and there is a way to stick this in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a [*while*](http://php.net/while) statement can be used. Remember to append `$x` outside the string when accessing the variable from `$_POST` - i.e. `$_POST['FirstName' . $x];` (though you could use double-quoted strings, since [the variables will be expanded](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing): `$_POST["FirstName$x"];`). Also the looping condition needs to be updated to *less than or equal* (i.e. `<=`) - otherwise the last name will not be processed.

So update the condition from :

```
 while($x < $userNum)
```

To:

```
while($x <= $userNum)
```

Then instead of using `$FirstName.$X` for the variable, just use a single name - e.g. `$FirstName`. As long as it is consistent, it will be used for that iteration separately.

```
$x = 1;
while($x <= $userNum)
{
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName' . $x];
    $FirstName = stripslashes($FirstName);
    $FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($FirstName);
    //use $FirstName to insert into database, or store in temporary structure
    ++$x;
}
```

But then also a [*for*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) statement could also be used. That can reduce the number of lines needed, as the variable to iterate (i.e. `$x`) is started and incremented in one line.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $userNum; $x++)
{
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName' . $x];
    $FirstName = stripslashes($FirstName);
    $FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($FirstName);
    //use $FirstName to insert into database, or store in temporary structure
}
```

And taking it one step further, a [*foreach*](http://php.net/foreach) statement can be used with [range()](http://php.net/range). With this structure, the variable doesn't need to be incremented manually and there is no need for the looping condition (i.e. `$x <= $userNum`).

```
foreach (range(1, $userNum) as $x)
{
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName' . $x];
    $FirstName = stripslashes($FirstName);
    $FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($FirstName);
    //use $FirstName to insert into database, or store in temporary structure
}
```

> Or maybe I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be and there is a way to stick this in an array

Yes you could store those names in an array, like this:

```
$FirstNames = array();
foreach (range(1, $userNum) as $x) {
    $FirstNames[$x] = $_POST['FirstName' . $x];
}
//use $FirstNames later to add values to the database
```

See a demonstration of this in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0ash-7ng7).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = 1;
$FirstName = array();
while($x < $userNum){
   $FirstName[]=$_POST["FirstName.$x"];
   $x++;
}
```

// you will get array of names then you can insert it to mysql

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried the code you posted, I had to move the
    .$x
to the outside of the " but then it worked perfectly! Thanks again

Comment: Actually, that will leave off the last name in the list... e.g. when `$userNum` ==1, the condition will never be true and the array will be empty; when `$userNum` == 2, the second (/last) name will not be added to the array...

Comment: I see. I ran a test and of course you are right. I had it echo the value of x at the end of each loop and even though it spits out 1-6 I only have 5 entries in the array